# Backup using find and ssh to off-site server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, find, backup, tar

I'm sure this has been been answered in bits and pieces on many sites, but somehow I can't seem to get this (as a whole) to work reliably.

Scenario:
I have a server that I would like to do incremental backups on (I'm thinking daily).

The files and directories I want to backup are located in the directories: `/home/` and `/srv/samba/`.

The backup should be .tar.gz to `/mnt/backup/` directory, and the filename should be something like `inc_backup_yyyymmdd.tar.gz`.

After the .tar.gz is successfully created, the file should be sent to an off-site server using ssh.

Right now the server creates a FULL backup once a week, and I manually send it off-site at random intervals (the .tar.gz size is about 60 GB, so it takes a while...).

Ideally I would like to .tar.gz ONLY regular files and folders. Files starting with . and ~ should be excluded, as well as directories starting with .

**There is one exception**:
In `/home/[user]/` and `/srv/samba/[someshare]/` folders I have ".recycle" folders, that should be included in the backup, but the file exclusions should be applied.

E.g.

```
/home/user/.hiddendirectory/ (excluded)
/home/user/.hiddendirectory/myfile.txt (excluded)
/home/user/myfile.txt (included)
/home/user/.myfile.txt (excluded)
/home/user/~myfile.txt (excluded)
/home/user/mydirectory/myfile.txt (included)
/home/user/.recycle/ (included)
/home/user/.recycle/~tmpfile (excluded)
/home/user/.recycle/.myfile (excluded)
/home/user/.recycle/myfile.txt (included)
```

I get started by using find:

> Please note that the following commands include non-standard operators (-not, -or), so if used, please ensure your system supports them

```
find /home -not -path '*/\.*' ! \( -name '.*' -or -name '~*' \) -mtime -1
```

This seems to find the files and folders I need. But immediately that I pipeline this to tar, it seems to ignore all the exclusions?

```
find /home -not -path '*/\.*' ! \( -name '.*' -or -name '~*' \) -mtime -1 -print0 | tar -zcvf /tmp/testbackup1.tar.gz --null -T -
```

I seem to get the correct result using the following:

```
find /home -not -path '*/\.*' ! \( -name '.*' -or -name '~*' \) -mtime -1 -print0 | tar -Avf /tmp/testbackup1.tar | gzip -c /tmp/testbackup1.tar > testbackup1.tar.gz
```

...but this seems overly complicated, and results in an empty tarball, although the tar has significant size? And none of these take into account the .recycle inclusion.

A bonus would be an encrypted tar.gz for added security.

Sending the file using SSH is the easy part.

My thoughts are to put this into a script file, that is executed by Cron.

The script would:

- Create the backup file (handling the naming procedure)
- Send the backup file over SSH to an off-site server
- Delete old files (e.g. 2 weeks) from the .recycle directories

The (in place) full backup would be executed once a month, and will also handle cleanup of old backup files (2 months).

So, in the end I would have 2 full backups and approx 60 incremental backups. Once a full backup is dropped, the incremental backups (refereing to that) would also be deleted. And all the backup files will be located on-site and off site.

Any advice (even totally new approaches) is really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use some of the well-established backup programs (attic, bup, obnam)?

Comment: why not to use `rsync`?

Comment: find has no operators called `-not` or `-or`. But if you like to use find and tar, why don't you just use  `star`?

Comment: Thank you for your ideas! All of those look like possible approaches, and I will have to do some research as to which approach suits my needs. @schily, That's weird. At least according to [link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) there are -not and -or operators for expressions, and they seem to work in my example.

Comment: These nonstandard operators are vendor unique extensions and specific to `gfind`. They are complete nonsense as there is an easy to remember standard, so you don't need them.

Comment: @schily, no matter what site I go to that describes the find command, I find those operators. Is there a site I can refer to, that only describes standard operators? I totally agree that one should use standardized approaches, but in this case I was unaware I used a non-standard approach.

Comment: I am of course aware that you did not do that intentionally. The problem with non-standard aliases however in such a help portal is that people may try to repeat the command on a certified UNIX that does not support the aliases. This is why a I warn about non-standard usage and why I am clearly informing readers of my man pages where my commands may have non-standard extensions.

Comment: I appreciate that! You live you learn, and that is why sites like these are usually packed with relevant and high quality information. Can you help me by providing a source to check for official, standardized approaches?

Comment: If you send an explicit list of files from `find` to `tar` you must exclude directories from that list. (Use `find ... -type f ...`) If `tar` encounters a directory it will process the entire tree rooted at that directory before moving on.

Comment: @Sisu, ignore schily.  he's on an anti-GNU crusade and refuses to believe that any GNU options are valid in any context, even when you're using GNU tools.  GNU `find` is standard on Ubuntu (and on all Linux distros).  GNU `find` *does* have `-not` and `-or` operators.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel, and your apparent aversion to using `rsync` is going to make that all the more painful. There are plenty of pre-existing solutions like [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), but if you're hell-bent on rolling your own I strongly suggest using `rsync` instead of cobbling together `find` and `tar`.

Comment: @Sisu - you may have only been able to find the non-standard GNU documentation. The official documentation is here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html Note that introducing aliases for features that exist in a standard compliant way since 40 years is counter productive and undermines the POSIX standard. It is a real problem for people who read non-standard command lines when they later try this on a standard comforming platform. Here is a  man page that does not confuse people: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/sfind.1.html

Comment: @Sisu - I still believe that the solution for your original question is `star`as it supports true incremental backups and on the other side, `star` includes support for `libfind`. Note that the `sfind` command mentioned above is based on `libfind` as well. Please have a look at the `star` man page at: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html star exists since 33 years, it is the oldest free `tar`implementation.